# jQuery onClick event

Tags: jquery, input, onclick

Cant seem to get this working. Any help would be great. I am somewhat of a beginner with jquery.

```
$('#add_button').click(function () {
    $("#add_button").hide();
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<input id='add_button' type='submit' class='add_now' value='' />
```

Seems simple enough, but clicking on the input does nothing. Is there a different method for targeting inputs? Thanks.

Comment: It seems that your form is currently posting back to the same page. Assuming you will never try to submit the form this way, you can use type='button', instead of submit.

Comment: Huh, still no luck with this method. I changed it to a button type. This is not inside a <form> tag. Does this change anything? I simple made it an input because of how it will be handled later.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure you include jQuery before your script:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

And put your code inside a document-ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add_button').click(function () {
        $("#add_button").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: you know what.. My function was closed off from the document ready function up above! Thanks, wouldn't have noticed this otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `return false;` to prevent the browser's default action.

Comment: This does not seem to make a difference. Could you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Return `false` from your function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that your jQuery is above the form. Try to move it below your HTML.