# Google Maps API addListener method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps Javascript API, and I want to make it so that when you a click a button on a map, a JS alert pops up.

Here's my JS code so far:

```
var gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

// Setting up and adding the boundary-changing buttons                                                  
var boundaryChangeArr = [
    '<h3 id="boundary-change-title">Change boundaries</h3>',
    '<div id="boundary-change-buttons-container">',
        '<input id="boundaries-states" class="boundary-change-button" type="button" name="StatesBoundaries" value="States" />',
        '<input id="boundaries-counties" class="boundary-change-button" type="button" name="CountiesBoundaries" value="Counties" />',
        '<input id="boundaries-tracts" class="boundary-change-button" type="button" name="TractsBoundaries" value="Tracts" />',
    '</div>'
];

// If there is no div  with the id 'boundary-change-container', make one
var boundaryChange = $('div#boundary-change-container');
if(boundaryChange.length===0){
    var boundaryChange = document.createElement('div');
    boundaryChange.id = 'boundary-change-container';
    boundaryChange.innerHTML = boundaryChangeArr.join('');
    gmap.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM].push(boundaryChange);
}; // DONE: if(boundaryChange.length===0)

google.maps.event.addListener(document.getElementById('boundaries-states'),
    'click',
    function(){
        alert('clicked');
    });
```

But when I click the button `boundaries-states`, nothing happens, and I don't even see any errors in Firebug, the Firefox plug-in that can check for JS errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?  Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that exhibits the problem?

Comment: 1. you want to use addDomListener for DOM objects (your buttons).  2. you can't access the buttons using getElementById until they have been added to the DOM. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LxM4e/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and re-reading the question, you would like to perform some work when clicking on the Button not on the Google Map.  In that case, you don't want to use  `google.maps.event.addListener` since that will listen for events (like click) on the map itself.

For the button, you can use the jQuery `click` event or if you're using a different javascript framework, they will likely have a click event as well.  For jQuery, you would do the following:

```
$('#boundaries-states').click(function () {
    //Do something
});
```

---

It looks like the `addListener` method takes the google Map object, not the HTML element for the map.  Take a look at the first example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events).

So if you're not already, you'll need to hold onto the reference to your map that is returned when you instantiate the map:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('boundaries-states'),
  mapOptions);
```

Once you have your map reference, you can add a listener using the map object, rather than the HTML element.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
  alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: I forgot to add: I have a line already that made the Google Maps object: `var gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);`

Comment: Ok, so for your case, use the `gmap` variable in the call to `addListener`, rather than `document.getElementById('boundaries-states')`.

Comment: In that case, the alert comes up when I click on the map, but not when I click `input#boundaries-states`. Is there any way to make the alert pop up when I click `input#boundaries-states`?

Comment: So it sounds like you want the click event to fire on your button element, not on the google map.  In that case, you can use the jQuery `click` event, not a google maps event listener.  See [this link](http://api.jquery.com/click/) for details and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697058/jquery-onclick-event) as well.